# I am getting an error in WordPress Function when I filter for a page slug

Tags: php, wordpress

This works on the Shop Page as it should, but not on any other page it throws an error.

It has something to do with if(is_page('shop'))

```html
function divi_engine_body_class( $classes ) {
   if(is_page('shop')) {
        $classes[] = 'woocommerce-page-SGARAGLINO';
        return $classes;
    }
}
add_filter( 'body_class','divi_engine_body_class',99999);
```

The error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: array_unique(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given in /wordpress/core/6.2.2/wp-includes/post-template.php:861

Answer (score 1):

The function returns the `$classes` variable only if `is_shop()` is truthy, when it should always return the `$classes` variable:

```php
function divi_engine_body_class( $classes ) {
   if ( is_page( 'shop' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'woocommerce-page-SGARAGLINO';
    }

    return $classes;
}
```

Filters must always return a value; if they do not, this will throw an error nearly always.